# search for partial match over multiple columns at sametime datagridview

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview, filter, rowfilter

I have a datagridview and i am surching in it ussing the following method

```
dvdonors.RowFilter = "STATUS = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' or PROJECT = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'" 'works compleate match
```

This allows me to search in either Status or project nice, but it rquiers a total match for a valid resualt.

the following code allows the user to search based upon a partial match..

```
dvdonors.RowFilter = String.Format("{0} LIKE '{1}%'", "STATUS", TextBox1.Text)
```

owever the problem is that this onlhy searches for a partial match in a specifide column.

The idea is to search for partial match over bothe columns so I have tryed to combine the codes as follows but this obviously dosnt work. Could somebody please assist?

```
dvdonors.RowFilter = String.Format("PROJECT LIKE '%{0}%' AND STATUS LIKE '%{1}%'", TextBox1.Text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `AND` which if what you are looking for does not exist in both columns you will not get anything. Either change it to `OR` or try this...

```
 dvdoners.RowFilter = "PROJECT LIKE '%" & Textbox1.Text & "%'" & " OR STATUS LIKE '%" & Texbox1.Text & "%'"
```

Also your second filter is looking for a field `1` you want `0` if using `String.Format`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, What if i have a datagrid with newly added columns and would like to filter over all colmuns regardelss of howmany could be added latter on

Comment: You could create a loop for all columns and build the filter.